# custom select image for an html form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-ui, select

I'm trying to figure out how to make a select menu in my html form that only shows the arrow. I want to make it so that there's a textfield for the search query, a search button, and then an arrow that allows the user to further specify what type of search they want to do.

How do I make it so that it only shows an arrow?

I tried looking into things like -webkit-appearance: none.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Ok I found a way to get what I want in Firefox, but I can't get it to work with Safari, Chrome, or Opera.

> -moz-appearance: menulist-button;

Comment: `border:none;` and/or `width:15px;`?

Comment: You might want to look at using an input, img tag which represents the arrow and then just call `$("#selectDiv").load(url-to-search-suggestions?s=bla)` when the img is clicked. That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want some sort of autocomplete box.  jQuery UI has a pretty good implementation of one you could check out: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/